# li as a main container for muiltiple li's inside ul not working

Tags: html, css, jotform

i am using **Jotforms** for my form requirement, i have downloaded the code and customizing the css and html for the design requirement that i have.

now **Jotforms** uses a set of `ul , li` for managing its HTMl structure now what i want to do is have a container inside the `ul` that will have some background and padding, i researched and got to know that is incorrect to have anything inside the `ul` other than `li's` and `ul's` and also i received an error due to not having an li child so i had to remove the div, no i am adding an li which has many li's inside it let me show you the code

**HTML**

```
<form class="jotform-form" action="https://submit.jotform.me/submit/81913120509450/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_81913120509450" id="81913120509450" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="formID" value="81913120509450" />
  <div class="form-all">
<ul class="form-section page-section">
      <li class="form-line" data-type="control_text" id="id_7">
        <div id="cid_7" class="form-input-wide">
          <div id="text_7" class="form-html" data-component="text">
            <h1>
              Logo Designing
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" data-type="control_text" id="id_9">
        <div id="cid_9" class="form-input-wide">
          <div id="text_9" class="form-html" data-component="text">
            <p>The best brands own a word or phrase and a related space in consumer's minds. which become each brand's position in the marketplace.brand image and identity to instantly have meaning for consumers and differentiate it from competitor brands</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" data-type="control_widget" id="id_10">
        <div id="cid_10" class="">
          <div style="width:100%;text-align:Left" data-component="widget-directEmbed">
            <div class="direct-embed-widgets " data-type="direct-embed" style="width:50px;height:50px">
              <div class="form_breadcrumbs_widget" id="form_breadcrumbs_widget_'10'">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var qidBreadcrumbs = '10';
                    var tabsCustomCssBreadcrumbs = 'numerically';
                    var navigateWithoutValidationBreadcrumbs = 'Yes';
                    var formTabsThemeBreadcrumbs = 'se-theme-maya-blue';
                    var numberTypeBreadcrumbs = 'numerically';
                </script>
                <script src="//widgets.jotform.io/breadcrumbs/min/scripts.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!--<div class="white-box">-->

        <!--<div class="white-box-padding">-->

          <!--<div class="shair1">-->

            <li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_dropdown" id="id_3">
              <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_3" for="input_3">
                What is your Brand Industry?
                <span class="form-required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div id="cid_3" class="form-input-wide jf-required">
                <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" id="input_3" name="q3_typeA" data-component="dropdown" required="">
                  <option value="">  </option>
                  <option value="uneeb"> uneeb </option>
                  <option value="uneeb2"> uneeb2 </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textbox" id="id_54">
              <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_54" for="input_54"> What is your Slogan? </label>
              <div id="cid_54" class="form-input-wide">
                <input type="text" id="input_54" name="q54_whatIs54" data-type="input-textbox" class="form-textbox" size="20" value="" data-component="textbox" />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textbox" id="id_55">
              <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_55" for="input_55"> What is your Company Name? </label>
              <div id="cid_55" class="form-input-wide">
                <input type="text" id="input_55" name="q55_whatIs" data-type="input-textbox" class="form-textbox" size="20" value="" data-component="textbox" />
              </div>
            </li>
          <!--</div>-->
          <!--<div class="shair2">-->
            <img src="images/shair.jpg"/>
          <!--</div>-->
          <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textarea" id="id_12">
            <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_12" for="input_12"> What is your Objective? </label>
            <div id="cid_12" class="form-input-wide">
            <textarea id="input_12" placeholder="For Example : Small to mid-size companies who need brand awareness, brand recognition and online lead generation,
            regardless of industr. We help all types of clients. Furthermore, we target people who want recognition
            through online presence and are readily accesible via web & social media." class="form-textarea" name="q12_typeA12" cols="40" rows="6" data-component="textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="form-line" data-type="control_text" id="id_15">
            <div id="cid_15" class="form-input-wide">
              <div id="text_15" class="form-html" data-component="text">
                <p>Upload Image or Sketch that might be helpful.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="form-line" data-type="control_fileupload" id="id_13">
            <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_13" for="input_13">  </label>
            <div id="cid_13" class="form-input-wide">
              <div data-wrapper-react="true">
                <div data-wrapper-react="true">
                  <div class="qq-uploader-buttonText-value">
                    Browse
                  </div>
                  <input type="file" id="input_13" name="q13_input13[]" multiple="" class="form-upload-multiple" data-imagevalidate="yes" data-file-accept="pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, csv, txt, rtf, html, zip, mp3, wma, mpg, flv, avi, jpg, jpeg, png, gif" data-file-maxsize="10854" data-file-minsize="0" data-file-limit="" data-component="fileupload" />
                </div>
                <span style="display:none" class="cancelText">
              Cancel
            </span>
                <span style="display:none" class="ofText">
              of
            </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="form-line" data-type="control_text" id="id_16">
            <div id="cid_16" class="form-input-wide">
              <div id="text_16" class="form-html" data-component="text">
                <p>Note : File size should be 500KB</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        <!--</div>-->
        <li id="cid_5" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_pagebreak">
          <div class="form-pagebreak" data-component="pagebreak">
            <div class="form-pagebreak-back-container">
              <button id="form-pagebreak-back_5" type="button" class="form-pagebreak-back " data-component="pagebreak-back">
                Back
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-pagebreak-next-container">
              <button id="form-pagebreak-next_5" type="button" class="form-pagebreak-next " data-component="pagebreak-next">
                Next
              </button>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both" class="pageInfo form-sub-label" id="pageInfo_5">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      <!--</div>-->
    </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

now if you notice there is an commented div named **white-box** this is the problem i have changed it to be li but this is the issue

[image: with Div]
you can see how the line follows in my editor and but when i change it to li

[image: with li]

event the console shows it as an independent li whereas every li after the class **white-box** should have been inside it,
[image]

it doesnt takes the whole space my editor shows it ends over there where it started and the editor tells the closing tag that should be aligned with this li says `ending tag matches nothing`
i am not sure what type of error i am making can someone guide me?

Comment: Really hard to understand what your actual problem is here. More proper verbal explanation, less screenshots would be nice. _“div named white-box this is the problem i have changed it to be li”_ - so you mean you changed that div to li, but left the rest of it as is? Then you would have nested LI directly into LI now, which is also not valid HTML.

Comment: _“now what i want to do is have a container inside the ul that will have some background and padding”_ - just around some of the items of that list, not all of them? Not directly possible, you would have to emulate it - either by formatting those LI themselves accordingly, or maybe by positioning a pseudo element behind the whole thing, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `img` tag contains in between the two `li` tags, THis is not an coding standard  , please remove the image from outside the `li`

Your img tag like as :

```
<li>
   </li>     
      <img src="images/shair.jpg"/>/*Remove from here*/
<li>
 </li>
```

Comment: that was a nice catch! it commented it completely but still the same issue.

Comment: i have added some more info and updated the answer for more clarification